# Build script change in the cargo registry seems to have no effect, so how can I fix the build script?

Tags: tensorflow, rust, rust-cargo

I added tensorflow to my rust project via the `cargo.toml` file which looks like this:

```ini
#...
[dependencies]
tensorflow = { version = "0.20.0", features = ["tensorflow_gpu"] }
```

When leaving out the `"tensorflow_gpu"` feature the project builds and runs without problems. But when building with the `"tensorflow_gpu"` feature it crashes with the error:

```
--- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidArchive("Could not find central directory end")', E:\rust\cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tensorflow-sys-0.23.0\build.rs:154:45
```

I figuered the error seems to be in the build script where the wrong `"libtensorflow-gpu-windows-x86_64-2.11.0.zip"` get's downloaded.

The build script output states, that it tries to download `"binary_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-gpu-windows-x86_64-2.11.0.zip"`, but after a bit of research I found out that the last stable GPU version of tensorflow for windows is `2.10.0`, so `2.11.0` can't be downloaded, thus crashing the unzip call, because that zip doesn't exist.

Searching through the `build.rs` file of `tensorflow-sys-0.23.0` I found the `VERSION` constant evaluating to `"2.11.0"` and a format expression:

```rust
let binary_url = format!(
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-{}-{}-{}-{}{}",
    proc_type,
    os,
    target_arch(),
    VERSION,
    ext
    );
```

that generates the binary url.

I tried changing both the VERSION constant to `"2.10.0"` and changing the format expression to

```rust
let binary_url = format!(
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-{}-{}-{}-2.10.0{}",
    proc_type,
    os,
    target_arch(),
    ext
    );
```

if the proc_type is `"gpu"`. But the build script still logs the wrong `binary_url` with version being `"2.11.0"`, so the changes I did to the build.rs file seemed to have no effect. I guess depending on an older tensorflow version should solve the problem, but then I can't use modern tensorlfow features, and I wan't to try them out, so that should only be my last option. So what can I do

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the code `let binary_url = format!(...`, try changing the two constants in the beginning of the build.rs:

```
const VERSION: &str = "2.10.0";
const TAG: &str = "v2.10.0";
```

The build.rs will not recompile if you just run `cargo build`, instead run `cargo clean -p tensorflow-sys` and than build.
Worked for me.

Also, i see that there is an issue for it in github: https://github.com/tensorflow/rust/issues/400